# Where to get logs for Gnome3 when "Oh no! Something has gone wrong." appears?

Tags: gnome3

I have recently upgraded my ArchLinux and Gnome3 got broken. On boot, GDM shows up (and works), however, when trying to log in Gnome3 session, I recieve "Oh no! Something has gone wrong." screen.

Other sessions (i3-wm) work well. Where could I get more useful information about what actually causes the problem? I tried to google where are the gnome3 log files are, but I was not successful.

Comment: Try /var/log for the Xorg logs instead. I suspect this has something to do with hardware acceleration Gnome 3 needs. What video card and what drivers are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Check with the command journalctl and check the logs under /var/log/gdm.

There's also the gnome-logs tool on Github: 
https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-logs